# Polymer: How to watch computed properties for changes

Tags: polymer

Given:

```
Polymer({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  computed: {
    name: '{{firstName}} {{lastName}}'
  },

  firstNameChanged: function() {
    console.log('firstNameChanged')
  },
  lastNameChanged: function() {
    console.log('lastNameChanged')
  },
  nameChanged: function() {
    console.log('nameChanged')
  },
```

If either the `firstName` or `lastName` is changed, then the `firstNameChanged` and `lastNameChanged` will fire, but the `nameChanged` never does. Does anyone know why and how I can fix it?

I'm on Polymer 0.5.x, just FYI.

Comment: I would recommend you to switch to the latest version of Polymer!